# Use Puppet Apache class to install Apache1 on CentOS

Tags: vagrant, puppet, apache-1.3

I'm trying to create a Vagrant setup using CentOS 6.4 and Apache 1.3 (this is for a legacy application). I am using Puppet (though if an answer in Chef is easier, I'd be happy to use it) and the [Puppetlabs Apache class](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache). The issue I'm having is that it installs Apache 2.2, but I don't see how to make it install Apache 1.3 instead.

What am I doing wrong and how can I do it right? (Answers of "Upgrade your app" will be downvoted - I don't have the authority to make that decision.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you're using doesn't explicitly expose a parameter to specify which **version** of the `httpd` package you want to install.

Instead of using Puppetlabs module, you could use the Apache module from Alessandro Franceschi (source [here](https://github.com/example42/puppet-apache) - also [on the forge](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/example42/apache))). If the package you need to install has a different name than `httpd`, the module exposes a `package` parameter which you can override like this:

```
class { 'apache':
  package => 'apache13',
}
```

If, instead, Apache 1.3 is provided by the same `httpd` package by declaring the specific version you want, you can rely on the `version` parameter:

```
class { 'apache':
  version => '1.3.39',
}
```

Clearly, you can also combine the two parameters together.

Answer (score 0):

using those modules return the following error on Redhat:

`Error 400 on SERVER: Illegal expression.`

A Type-Name is unacceptable as function name in a Function Call at `/etc/puppet/modules/apache/man.`